# R Shiny takes a long time to load dataset, despite not being that large

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing an app using Shiny to display the data from our lab online so that other users can browse and use it. I am still only at the early levels, but am having trouble letting the app load in a reasonable timeframe.

My dataset is saved as a .RDa file consisting of around 150 obs of around 19000 variables (so 19000 columns with column names, and 150 rows without row names). The file is around 9MB when viewed in Finder (although when I load it into RStudio, for some reason the size increases to 25MB in the Environment display).

The App is designed to allow the selection of one of the variables, perform several simple comparative calculations on it, and then display the results as both a plot and table. There are tickboxes selecting which calculations to perform, some of which are TRUE by default and some of which are FALSE.

I do get a couple of Warning messages when it does load, as it still tries to display points and tables for calculations which are selected as FALSE by default, and the warnings disapeer when I set these calculations as TRUE by default, but doesn't speed up the loading so I don't think this is what is slowing it down.

The data is loaded and the dropdown box where variables are selected is defined as follows:

```
load("DataFile.RDa")
GeneNames <- colnames(DataFile)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #first wellpanel for selecting gene to look at
      wellPanel(
        selectInput(
          inputId = "gene_select",
          label = NULL,
          choices = GeneNames,
          selected = "ACTB"))
)))
```

My issue is when first loading up the Shiny app, it takes a surprisingly long time to load, and when I have uploaded it to Shinyapps.io sometimes takes so long that it timeouts and you are forced to reload the page. Once the app is loaded however, changing the gene selection or changing the calculations to perform happens almost instantly. And if I upload a severely cropped version of my data (20 variables instead of 19000) it loads very fast.

Due to this, I believe that the problem is with the initial loading of the data rather than any problem with the calculations. Is there some trick I am missing with the loading of data?

EDIT: Also I have found that it loads very fast when viewing the site on mobile, it is only slow when loading on desktop.

Comment: Try to use an uncompressed version of the dataset to decrease the loading time. For example `saveRDS(..., compress = FALSE)`.

Comment: Hmm so I got saveRDS/readRDS working, and this does seem to speed up loading times in RStudio, but not on Shinyapps.io.
I also noticed that when running on Shinyapps.io the UI selectInput elements load in slowly too, I assume because they are taking a long time to populate the dropdown boxes with all 19000 possible gene entries.